# Elasticsearch query term search, how to do it with _source?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm new with elasticsearch, I'am using version 5.1.2. 
I have this index, I don't know If I created well with the _source field.
I want a query that returns all registers with loc = XXY and part = Z, how can I do it? I am trying with this but not works. Any idea?

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 107271,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "po",
        "_id": "0",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "loc": "XXX",
          "part": "YY",
          "order_qty": "16",
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "po",
        "_id": "14",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "loc": "XXY",
          "part": "Z",
          "order_qty": "7",
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "po",
        "_id": "19",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "loc": "XXY",
          "part": "Z",
          "order_qty": "8",
        }
       ...
```

The query that I am using but not works:

```
GET my_index/po/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "loc" : "XXY", "part": "Z"}
    }
}
```

Mappings:

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "po": {
        "properties": {
          "loc": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "order_qty": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "part": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
POST my_index/po/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "loc":  "XXY" }},
        { "match": { "part": "Z"   }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Some additional information about match query - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

Comment: what does it mean it's not working? may be you have wrong data or wrong mappings, plz show them

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html get mappings

Comment: "mappings": {
      "po": {
        "properties": {
          "loc": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256

Comment: "order_qty": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256

Comment: "part": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256

Comment: please remove them from comments and add them to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134468/discussion-between-mysterion-and-joan-triay).